# multi catch exception processing and polymorphisme

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have 2 methodes

```
process (MyExceptionType1 e){
...
}

process (MyExceptionType2 e){
...
}
```

and the try/catch :

```
try{

...

}catch (MyExceptionType1 | MyExceptionType2 e){
process(e);
}
```

The compiler reject the call process(e) with this error :
no suitable method found for processException(java.lang.Exception)

just as if it ignores the types given in the catch clause.

but it accepts

```
}catch (MyExceptionType1 e){
process(e);
}catch(MyExceptionType2 e){
process(e);
}
```

How to explain this behaviour ?

Thank you for your help.

Nader

Comment: your process takes an Exception as input? how about clarifying?

Comment: Which JAVA version you are using? Multiple Catch block is not supported prior JAVA 7..

Comment: you also show `processException` and `process` - where is the first method? voting to close as un-clear, unless you make it better of course

Comment: Neither of your `process` methods accepts **both** types of exception, so neither method can be used to resolve the `process(e)` call during compilation.

Comment: When using a multi-catch block the type of the exception in the catch block is always the common type of the exceptions caught. That is generally either `RuntimeException` or `Exception` for the base-exceptions provided by Java. Would you e.g. create a class `MyException` derived from `RuntimeException` and two classes `MyException1` and `MyException2` derived from `MyException` and make a multi-catch catching `MyException1` and `MyException2` the type of the exception in the catch block would be of `MyException`. In your case the base class for the two exceptions is `Exception`.

Comment: You could do an `instanceof` on the exception and then parse it to your types of exceptions to call the correct `process` method but honestly just using multiple `catch` blocks is cleaner imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not permitted because at compile time, the type of variable `e` in `(MyExceptionType1 | MyExceptionType2 e)` is of the most specific common super-type of `MyExceptionType1` and `MyExceptionType2`.

Whatever the common supertype of `MyExceptionType1` and `MyExceptionType2` is, it's too broad for just `MyExceptionType1` or just `MyExceptionType2` as argument to a method. This explains why it works with single catch blocks.

The common super-class of those two classes is likely to be `Exception` if these two are not extending a different exception class. So, you may need to check instances of the exception objects (that is, if you do not want to use the multi-catch):

```
process (Exception e){ //If the exceptions extend a common specific type, use it here
    if(e instanceof MyExceptionType1)
       process((MyExceptionType1) e);
    else if (e instanceof MyExceptionType2)
       process((MyExceptionType2) e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check Exception type and then redirect to the desired method.

```
catch(Exception1 | Exception2 e){
            if(e instanceof Exception1)
                m1((Exception1)e);
            if(e instanceof Exception2)
                m1((Exception2)e);
        }
```